# How to print nested JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, nested-lists

I tried to print a list from a JSON object and I got the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

The whole JSON object looks like this:

```
{'status': 0, 
'body': 
{'activities': [
{'steps': 4144, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-10', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': False}, 
{'steps': 4962, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-11', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': False}, 
{'steps': 4052, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-12', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 4375, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-13', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 5705, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-14', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 5831, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-15', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 6460, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-16', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 1853, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-17', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 4933, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-18', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}, 
{'steps': 3247, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-19', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}], 
'more': False, 'offset': 0}}
```

I tried to print with the following code:

```
print(json_response2["body"["activities"["steps"][0]["date"]]])
```

and the error occurred.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `print(json_response2["body"]["activities"][0]["steps"], json_response2["body"]["activities"][0]["date"])`

Comment: What do you like to print each "steps" and "date" or just from the first item?

Comment: @LeoArad i like to know to print the whole, but for a first try,  i just wanted to print the first line.

To print all the items, i think i would need a foreloop right?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you can look at my answer on how to use the for loop to print all "steps" and "date" from each activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the elements of "date" and "steps" like the following

```
json_response2 = {'status': 0,
'body':
{'activities': [
{'steps': 4144, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-10', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': False},
{'steps': 4962, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-11', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': False},
{'steps': 4052, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-12', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 4375, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-13', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 5705, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-14', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 5831, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-15', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 6460, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-16', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 1853, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-17', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 4933, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-18', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True},
{'steps': 3247, 'deviceid': None, 'timezone': 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'date': '2020-06-19', 'brand': 18, 'is_tracker': True}],
'more': False, 'offset': 0}}

for i in json_response2["body"]["activities"]:
    print(i["steps"], i["date"])
```

This will print the "date" and "steps" for each activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(json_response2["body"]["activities"][0]["steps"])
```

You should use the print statement like this. This will print the 'steps' data of the first activity.

If you want to print the 'date' data you can use this statement:

```
print(json_response2["body"]["activities"][0]["date"])
```